# Tag Synonym Requests

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Please collect your tag synonym requests here, to keep it all in one nice convenient spot. Basically, if you see two tags that are identical or nearly so, please let us know here so it can be fixed.

Upvote if you agree it should be done as suggested, comment otherwise.